# xwiki/velocity recent changes

Tags: velocity, xwiki

by default the recent pages code that can be found does not do what I want it to do.
How can I get

- a media-wiki-like version of recent changes
- -and/or-
- the last 10 changed pages

preferably using velocity.

Many greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is probably based on a database request to get the last pages so that mean you can limit the number of result easily either as a $xwiki.search method parameter (see http://tinyurl.com/7r8od94 for example) or better using setLimit if you are using the new query service (see http://tinyurl.com/7y99smg).

If you can point me to the exact code you are talking about I can probably give you more details on what to modify.

Comment: this might be exactly what I need. Hadn't found these pages yet.